why do i still have speed accumulation after i reset everything
I'm making a flappy bird game using js and there is a problem where everytime I reset because I lost there is a speed accumulation.
I tried resetting the clouds and pipes and everything but still it didn't work


const canvas = document.getElementById('gameCanvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');


canvas.width = window.innerWidth * 0.8;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight * 0.8;


let birdX = 50;
let birdY = canvas.height / 2;
let birdRadius = 20;
let gravity = 0.3;
let jumpStrength = 10;
let velocity = 0;


let pipes = [];
let pipeWidth = 50;
let pipeGap = 150;
let pipeSpeed = 2;
let pipeFrequency = 90;
let pipeColor = '#2e7d32';


let clouds = [];
let cloudSpeed = 0.5;
let cloudFrequency = 300;


let score = 0;
let gameOver = false;
let gameStarted = false;



document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
  if (event.code === 'Space') {
    if (!gameStarted || gameOver) {
      gameStarted = true;
      gameOver = false;
      resetGame();
      startGame();
    } else {
      velocity = -jumpStrength;
    }
  }
});

function resetGame() {
  birdY = canvas.height / 2;
  pipes = [];
  clouds = [];
  velocity = 0;
  score = 0;
  frameCount = 0;
  pipeSpeed = 2;
  cloudSpeed = 0.5;
}

function startGame() {
  requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}


function drawBird() {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(birdX, birdY, birdRadius, 0, Math.PI * 2);
  ctx.fillStyle = '#f44336';
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.closePath();
}


function drawPipes() {
  for (let i = 0; i < pipes.length; i++) {
    ctx.fillStyle = pipeColor;
    ctx.fillRect(pipes[i].x, 0, pipeWidth, pipes[i].topHeight);
    ctx.fillRect(pipes[i].x, pipes[i].bottomY, pipeWidth, canvas.height - pipes[i].bottomY);
  }
}


function movePipes() {
  for (let i = 0; i < pipes.length; i++) {
    pipes[i].x -= pipeSpeed;
  }
  if (pipes.length > 0 && pipes[0].x < -pipeWidth) {
    pipes.shift();
  }
}


function generatePipes() {
  if (frameCount % pipeFrequency === 0) {
    let topHeight = Math.floor(Math.random() * (canvas.height - pipeGap));
    pipes.push({
      x: canvas.width,
      topHeight: topHeight,
      bottomY: topHeight + pipeGap
    });
  }
}


function drawClouds() {
  ctx.fillStyle = '#ffffff';
  for (let i = 0; i < clouds.length; i++) {

    let radius = clouds[i].radius;
    let x = clouds[i].x;
    let y = clouds[i].y;

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(x + radius * 0.5, y, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2);
    ctx.arc(x - radius * 0.5, y - radius * 0.3, radius * 0.8, 0, Math.PI * 2);
    ctx.arc(x + radius * 1, y - radius * 0.1, radius * 0.6, 0, Math.PI * 2);
    ctx.arc(x + radius * 1.5, y - radius * 0.2, radius * 0.7, 0, Math.PI * 2);
    ctx.arc(x + radius * 2, y, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();
  }
}


function moveClouds() {
  for (let i = 0; i < clouds.length; i++) {
    clouds[i].x -= cloudSpeed;
  }
  if (clouds.length > 0 && clouds[0].x + clouds[0].radius * 2 < 0) {
    clouds.shift();
  }
}


function generateClouds() {
  if (frameCount % cloudFrequency === 0) {
    let cloudRadius = Math.random() * 30 + 20;
    let cloudY = Math.random() * (canvas.height / 2);
    clouds.push({
      x: canvas.width,
      y: cloudY,
      radius: cloudRadius
    });
  }
}


function drawBorder() {
  ctx.strokeStyle = '#000000';
  ctx.lineWidth = 5;
  ctx.strokeRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}


function checkCollisions() {

  let birdTop = birdY - birdRadius;
  let birdBottom = birdY + birdRadius;
  let birdLeft = birdX - birdRadius;
  let birdRight = birdX + birdRadius;


  for (let i = 0; i < pipes.length; i++) {
    if (birdRight > pipes[i].x && birdLeft < pipes[i].x + pipeWidth) {
      if (birdTop < pipes[i].topHeight || birdBottom > pipes[i].bottomY) {
        gameOver = true;
      }
    }
  }


  if (birdBottom > canvas.height || birdTop < 0) {
    gameOver = true;
  }
}



function update() {
  if (!gameOver) {
    velocity += gravity;
    birdY += velocity;

    movePipes();
    generatePipes();
    moveClouds();
    generateClouds();
    checkCollisions();
    score++;
  }
}


function draw() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);


  ctx.fillStyle = '#70c5ce';
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);


  drawBorder();


  drawClouds();


  drawPipes();

  if (gameStarted && !gameOver) {

    drawBird();


    ctx.fillStyle = '#ffffff';
    ctx.font = '24px Arial';
    ctx.fillText('Score: ' + score, 20, 40);
  }

  if (!gameStarted) {
    ctx.fillStyle = '#ffffff';
    ctx.font = '24px Arial';
    ctx.fillText('Press Space to Start', canvas.width / 2 - 120, canvas.height / 2);
  }

  if (gameOver) {

    drawBird();


    ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)';
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    ctx.fillStyle = '#ffffff';
    ctx.font = '36px Arial';
    ctx.fillText('Game Over!', canvas.width / 2 - 100, canvas.height / 2 - 20);
    ctx.font = '24px Arial';
    ctx.fillText('Press Space to Restart', canvas.width / 2 - 120, canvas.height / 2 + 20);
  }


  frameCount++;


  if (gameStarted && !gameOver) {
    update();
  }


  requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}


let frameCount = 0;


draw();
body {
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #70c5ce;
}

canvas {
  border: 5px solid #000000;
}
<canvas id="gameCanvas"></canvas>




You'll need to explain more; what do you specifically mean by "speed accumulation"? Your code references neither "speed" nor "accumulation". Is it the velocity variable?

It seems we need some clarity. What exactly is going on with your "speed accumulation" are you saying that when you restart the game the speed accumulation is at the speed of the previous game before it ended?
Also, what do you mean by "it didn't work." Did you get an error, or are you changing variables and seem to not have any change in game?

by speed accumulation is that the next game after the player dies is double the speed of the last game and so on

and it didnt work as the bug didnt get fixed

What makes you think the speed is accumulating between games? I added console.log(velocity, birdY) to the update() function, and the results were the same when I restarted.
